# Why is itertools.islice only returning one value, when I entered 10 as the stop parameter?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will print 10 random dice rolls. This is my code:

```
import itertools
from random import randint

def gen_rndtup(n):
    a = randint(1,n-1)
    b = randint(1, n-2)
    yield (a, b)

if __name__=='__main__':
    n = 7
    dice_roll = itertools.islice(gen_rndtup(n), 10)
    print(list(dice_roll))
```

This is the output I get: `[(4, 2)]` (obviously the numbers are different every time, due the random number generator).

From what I read in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), `itertools.islice(gen_rndtup(n), 10)` should return the first 10 tuples generated by `gen_rndtup(n)`, so why is it only returning one?

Comment: `gen_rndtup` only returns 1 item. Did you want a loop in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `gen_rndtup` only yields one tuple.  If you want `gen_rndtup` to give you more than one value, you need it to `yield` multiple times (either by having multiple `yield` statements or by putting your `yield` in some kind of loop).

Answer (score 1):

Your generator yields one result and then stops yielding results.

```
def gen_rndtup(n):
    a = randint(1,n-1)
    b = randint(1, n-2)
    while True:
        yield (a, b)
```

will produce the what you expect